# Tamaño de un DIV - Bootsrap

Tags: html, bootstrap

Hola estoy tratando de poner un `div`, como se el tamaño o el ancho es de 12, lo que quiero es poner 2 `div` de tamaño 6 cada uno, no estoy familiarizado con el diseño por eso uso bootstrap, el div que quiero descoponer es el segundo si bien vemos una leyenda de colores lo quiero agrupar en 2 partes o 2 divuna de profesores y otra de almnos espero me ayuden :
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el cosigo del segundo `div`

```
<div class="box box-solid box-primary">
                <div class="box-header with-border">
                    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
                    <h3 class="box-title">ASISTENCIA POR FECHA &nbsp;&nbsp;[&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o"></i> Fecha : <span id="fecha_adjudicacion"><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></span>&nbsp;]</h3>
                    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
                        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
                        <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="box-body border-radius-none">
                    <div col-xs-6>
                        <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="description-block border-right">
                                <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success" id="total_docentes">97% - 100%</span></h5>
                                <br>
                                <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO DOCENTE</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="description-block border-right">
                                <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-warning" id="docentes_faltan">90% - 96%</span></h5>
                                <br>
                                <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO DOCENTE</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="description-block border-right">
                                <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger" id="total_alumnos">0% - 95%</span></h5>
                                <br>
                                <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO DOCENTE</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div  col-xs-6>
                        <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="description-block border-right">
                                <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success" id="total_docentes">98% - 100%</span></h5>
                                <br>
                                <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO ALUMNO</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="description-block border-right">
                                <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-warning" id="docentes_faltan">94% - 97%</span></h5>
                                <br>
                                <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO ALUMNO</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div><!-- /.col -->
                        <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
                            <div class="description-block border-right">
                                <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger" id="total_alumnos">0% - 93%</span></h5>
                                <br>
                                <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO ALUMNO</span>
                            </div><!-- /.description-block -->
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Comment: Los _divs_ internos le aplicas un atributo inexistente `<div col-xs-6 >` , debería ser `<div  class="col-xs-6">`

Comment: Edite la imagen

Answer (score 0):

No estas dándoles una clase a los divs.

Hiciste esto: `<div  col-xs-6>`

Debería ser : `<div class="col-xs-6">`

Te dejo tu código corregido:

```html
<div class="box box-solid box-primary">
  <div class="box-header with-border">
    <i class="fa fa-th"></i>
    <h3 class="box-title">ASISTENCIA POR FECHA &nbsp;&nbsp;[&nbsp;<i class="fa fa-calendar-minus-o"></i> Fecha : <span id="fecha_adjudicacion"><?php echo date('Y-m-d'); ?></span>&nbsp;]</h3>
    <div class="box-tools pull-right">
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="collapse"><i class="fa fa-minus"></i></button>
      <button class="btn btn-box-tool" data-widget="remove"><i class="fa fa-times"></i></button>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="box-body border-radius-none">
    <div class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="description-block border-right">
          <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success" id="total_docentes">97% - 100%</span></h5>
          <br>
          <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO DOCENTE</span>
        </div><!-- /.description-block -->
      </div><!-- /.col -->
      <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="description-block border-right">
          <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-warning" id="docentes_faltan">90% - 96%</span></h5>
          <br>
          <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO DOCENTE</span>
        </div><!-- /.description-block -->
      </div><!-- /.col -->
      <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="description-block border-right">
          <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger" id="total_alumnos">0% - 95%</span></h5>
          <br>
          <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO DOCENTE</span>
        </div><!-- /.description-block -->
      </div>
    </div>
    <div  class="col-xs-6">
      <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="description-block border-right">
          <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-success" id="total_docentes">98% - 100%</span></h5>
          <br>
          <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO ALUMNO</span>
        </div><!-- /.description-block -->
      </div><!-- /.col -->
      <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="description-block border-right">
          <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-warning" id="docentes_faltan">94% - 97%</span></h5>
          <br>
          <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO ALUMNO</span>
        </div><!-- /.description-block -->
      </div><!-- /.col -->
      <div class="text-center col-sm-2 col-xs-2">
        <div class="description-block border-right">
          <h5 class="description-header" ><span style="font-size:15px" class="label label-danger" id="total_alumnos">0% - 93%</span></h5>
          <br>
          <span class="description-text">SEMAFORO ALUMNO</span>
        </div><!-- /.description-block -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Necesito que el div primary se divida en 2